# How to Serialize Queryset.values in Django?

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-queryset

Suppose, I have a query:

```
qs = demo.objects.filter(id=id).values_list('name','price')
```

And I have a  serializer:

```
Class DemoSerialzier(serialzier.Modelserialzier):
      class Meta:
            model = Demo
            fields = ['name','price']
```

How do I serialize my **qs**? when I pass my qs through the serializer it gives an AttributeError. Where Django tried to find a field on the serializer and the tuple object has no attribute 'name'.

Comment: You should pass the queryset and not the values list queryset: remove the call to `values_list`

Comment: I have three models related to each other. Using values list I can make my query faster that's why I want to use this. Any alternative idea how to achieve this?

Comment: Can you add the models and the actual query to your question? The provided query looks to just be fetching two fields on a model and no relations

Comment: You can use `only()` if you want to only retrieve certain fields from the DB

Comment: like:
qs = Demo.objects.filter(a_fk__another_fk__id = id, a_fk__date_time=timezone.now())
I want to make it faster. can you check

Answer (score 0):

Because the `values_list` method returns a list of tuples and the serializer is looking for an object. If you desire to use `values_list` instead of the serializer, you can pass the `values_list` result directly to the response.

```py
import itertools

# This will return list of tuples.
# To make it flat we have to use itertools chain.
qs = demo.objects.filter(id=id).values_list('name','price')
qs = list(itertools.chain(*qs)
return Response(qs)
```